# how to fetch the token using basic Auth in REST api

Tags: json, xml, rest, sap-pi

I have a requirement to call the REST webservice to fetch the file and transfer to a folder (REST - SAP PO - SFTP).

Before calling the actual REST api to fetch file, I need to call a Login REST api using basic authorization which will return the Token and logon key which has to be passed in second REST api and content-type is “application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

Login Input format: Call the URL via POST method with JSON object serialized and set parameter.

```
obj={
  "login":"my_email@company.com",
  "pword":"my_password"
}
```

NOTE: To make the request calls, a JSON object will need to be created and passed as a POST form parameter obj={jsonObject}

How can we send object using REST adapter?

Comment: See https://blogs.sap.com/2023/01/11/oauth-2.0-authentication-for-sap-pi-po-rest-sender-channel/

Comment: Thanks for the blog, but I need to poll the third party URL to fetch the token for which I am using REST polling method. They have given only basic credentials not OAuth.

Need to pass the credentials like below which I am not sure how to pass:
obj={
  "login":"my_email@company.com",
  "pword":"my_password"
}

Comment: Read following.  It uses username/password.  OP recommends testing first with Postman : https://blogs.sap.com/2019/02/14/cloud-integration-inbound-http-connections-using-oauth-client-credentials-grant/

Comment: Hi, can you please suggest how can we include the word 'obj={Json object}' before request message.

Comment: You are sending an HTTP request and getting back an HTTP response.  The HTTP header Content-Type is the type of data in the body of the Request.  The HTTP header Accept is the type of data you expect to get back in the body of the response.  See following for adding a HTTP header to a SAP : https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_JAM_COLLABORATION/9981b6fb8453459d8103a04d674ebe0f/62eeb11a740f4fc587bb304840a1b9af.html